# ODatabaseException OrientDB Record Error

Tags: orientdb

I'm struggling to fix my orientdb database. I'm getting the error:

> Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error on retrieving record #58:65894 (cluster: cluster_name_here)

I'm running *REPAIR DATABASE --fix-graph* and that's when i get this error. Is there any other suggestions in approaching this? This is also the case when running *CHECK DATABASE*

I tried using this link as a resource: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Repair-Database.html

Comment: Hi Muppet, which version of orientdb you use?

Comment: Im using OrientDB Version: v.2.2.32

Comment: Can you increase heap size and after that run REPAIR DATABASE --fix-graph?